# Sitemap/robots.txt configuration conflict

Tags: seo, robots.txt, google-search-console

[My robots.txt](http://festivals.ie/robots.txt) contains the following rules:

```
Disallow: /api/
Allow: /
Allow: /apiDocs
```

The `/apiDocs` URL is in the sitemap, but according to Google Webmaster Tools, these robots.txt rules prohibit it from being crawled. I want to prevent all URLs that match `/api/*` from being crawled, but allow the URL `/apiDocs` to be crawled.

How should I change my `robots.txt` to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Line breaks aren’t allowed in a record (you have one between your `Disallow` and the two `Allow` lines).
- You don’t need `Allow: /` (it’s the same as `Disallow:`, which is the default).
- You disallow crawling of `/api/` (which is any URL whose path starts with "api" followed by a "/"), so there is no need for `Allow: /apiDocs` as it’s allowed anyway.

So your fallback record should look like:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /login/
Disallow: /logout/
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /error/
Disallow: /festival/subscriptions
Disallow: /artistSubscription
Disallow: /privacy
Disallow: /terms
Disallow: /static
Disallow: /api/
```

When a bot is matched by this "fallback" record, it is allowed to crawl URLs whose paths start with `apiDocs`.